# Binding the value of an object's property to a data bound ComboBox in .NET WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Currently building a WinForms data collection tool using C# and have been able to implement the binding of the values of my underling object/entity's properties to controls on the my form, e.g. TextBoxes, MaskedTextBoxes and Checkboxes to properties on my domain model class (e.g. Person class).  However, I have not been able to do this binding successfully with the ComboBox control.

With my Person class looking basically like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int? Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the ComboBox's DataSource property to bind to a Dictionary and setting the ValueMember and DisplayMember accordingly.  Doing so successfully populates that ComboBox with my reference data (display value and coded value) at run-time.

```
Dictionary<int, string> genderValues = repository.GetGenderValues()
cboGender.DataSource = new BindingSource(genderValues, null);
cboGender.ValueMember = "Key";
cboGender.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

However, when I try to bind my Person object's property 'Gender' to this ComboBox, following the pattern that worked with other control types (TextBox, CheckBox, etc.)

```
cboGender.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("ValueMember", _currentPerson, "Gender"));
```

The value of Gender on my person object is always NULL even after selecting an item in the Gender ComboBox.  Perhaps I am overlooking an additional step needed for binding the ValueMember of a ComboBox           to a object property?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<Person>` as the DataSource of the BindingSource (so you can use it for all the other Controls), setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to the properties you want as the Items' Text and corresponding value? What's the use of a (undefined) Dictionary here?

Answer (score 0):

`ValueMember` is a string and it does not change with a different selection in the combobox. You need to use one of the `Selected...` properties. Since it's an int, use `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Changing the statement for creating the Binding for the ComboBox to use SelectedValue doesn't seem to do the trick.  After making the change and running the solution, after selecting an option in the Gender ComboBox, if the ComboBox loses focus the control appears to un-select the option that was just selected.  Interrogating the underlying "_currentPerson" object also reveals that the Gender property's value is still NULL.  I confirmed that there are no events hooked up to the Gender ComboBox that would interfere.

Comment: Also tried with the "SelectedItem" property - ComboBox does not un-select the option like with "SelectedValue" after losing focus - but the underlying object still has a NULL values for Gender.

Comment: Well then you have two problems. I would try binding to a collection of some class instead of a Dictionary and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Created a Gender class with just two properties - DisplayValue and CodedValue -- created a call that returns an IList<Gender> with my same KeyValue pairs as the Dictionary<int, string> from the repository and assigned the corresponding DisplayMember and ValueMember of the Gender class to the Gender ComboBox.  ComboBox populates at run-time properly with DisplayValues.  However, retried using "SelectedItem" and "SelectedValue" properties in the create Binding statement for the ComboBox, but no luck -- property remains NULL in underlying object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
cboGender.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", genderValues, "Value", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```